# Can a site use other site's cookie?

Tags: cookies, browser, web

Say, a site example.com stores a cookie named `id`. Now, can another site access the cookie named `id`?

Comment: I think its not possible

Comment: were either of the answers below useful to you rony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers should never send cookies back to sites on different domains (third parties) to the originator (first-party), however depending on how the domain is set in the cookie they might be passed back to other subsites (e.g. a cookie with domain .example.com originating from me.example.com would also be sent back to you.example.com, them.example.com, etc).

Answer (score 2):

No.A site can only retrieve the information that it has placed on your hard disk.It can't access any other cookie's information.